# php auth sending specifc users to a specific page

Tags: php

first off third question I've asked and all have been answered well! So thanks to everybody who reads my posts (and others I guess)

I've gotten as far as I can without complete help on this one. I need to create a username and password section. I've done this before using htaccess, `htauth` files. Works well. Secure, and log's them in fine.  What I'm looking for though is some sort of script that will take a specific user to a specific page after login.

```
User1= user1.php
user2= user2.php
```

Ect.

Is this possible without a whole lot of work? I can make workarounds where the users login to the main index, then go where they need to, but then anyone logged in can go to anyone's page.

I'm not asking anyone to write the code. But even some guidance to some tutorials would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the page is authenticated using .htaccess, upon successful login the username is available as `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']`.

So you can either redirect the user using Location, or even better, directly include() the desired file.

You can place the user1.php, user2.php, ... files in a directory of their own, with a .htaccess that disallows direct access. This won't stop PHP from being able to include the files, and this way only the authenticated user can have access to his file.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']))
{
    $pvdir = './user_private_files/';
    // "basename" in case we log in little Jack Folders (Bobby Tables's cousin)
    $user = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']));
    $file = $pvdir.$user.'.php';
    if (file_exists($file))
    {
        include $pvdir."any_common_code_at_the_beginning_of_user_files.php";
        include $file;
        include $pvdir."any_common_code_at_the_end_of_user_files.php";
        exit();
    }
    include ugly_error.php;
}
```

Comment: SO assuming lets say "User1" log's in. This  "$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']" will be USER1 automatically? I'm unsure of include() how would that look? Sorry for my...noobness. lol. I'm good with some things. This is not one of my strong points

Comment: To understand your code: $user in the end of the code will just display the username. And then you're take $file = basically the username or ($user).php

Comment: Very usefull. Puts me on the right track. Would this code go to a general index.php first? Then do the redirect from there?

Comment: Yes. Except that you don't strictly need the redirect. By directly including the private file of each user, you implicitly protect it against exploiting, even if one were to know the method and the target user's ID. With a redirect, this would not be possible -- unless you again added authentication to every private file, and here you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

htauth is .. old :D

Well, in any case. You can fetch the user credentials from the `$_SERVER` variable somewhere and switch based on that.

`var_dump($_SERVER);` to see which property you need.

Then use `header("Location: /go/here.html");` to redirect the user.

Comment: I'm not set on using htauth. It's just how I've done it in the past. I can create a DB of usernames and pw's and direct them using some other script. I'm just unsure of how to direct them otherwise+

Comment: How would it know "/go/here.html" would be specific to user1, and user 2 would be "go/here2.html"

Comment: Yes, how do you know? This totally depends on what kinds of users you have. It's completely up to you.